# NullPointerException in a simple ArrayList.add function?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm getting used to java again and was experimenting with collections. I have the following very basic code but I can't seem to find the reason why I get an Nullpointer exception:

```
   import java.util.*;

    public class Event

{
    private ArrayList<String> fans;

    public Event()
    {
        ArrayList<String> fans = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void registerUser(String user)
    {    
        fans.add(user);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've initialized a local `fans` in your constructor, so your instance variable `fans` is not explicitly initialized, so it's still `null` in `registerUser`.

Change

```
ArrayList<String> fans = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
fans = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your class field in your constructor. Remove the datatype declaration.

```
public Event(){
    fans = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```